# Instagram API "relationship" permission not granted

Tags: permissions, instagram-api, relationships

We are a brand that is building a website using Instagram API to help us manage our audience. We want users to type in their Instagram nicknames in a form, so we can start following them (or request that if their profile is private) with our Brand account and we wanted to use the "relationships" permission, but Instagram didn't grant us the access:

"This permission (relationships) is only granted to **apps that enable brands and advertisers to manage their followers**. We do not grant access to apps that do not fall into these categories."

If I understand this correctly, Instagram does not grant us the access as we are not managing our followers, but managing people we follow. Is there any way we can work that around?

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need to create an app for it, you can just use Instagram App to follow or request users.

Instagram API has rate limit on follow API call, you can only follow 30 users per hour, so you cannot really create an app to follow a lot of users automatically, you are better of following manually using the API or Instagram.com website.

Comment: Well, if we wanted to follow our users, we would have to create a database and then do it manually, so we were looking for and option to automatize this process - this way we don't need an additional person to do the "following" work.